# How to deploy Angular SPA from BitBucket to Azure?

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, continuous-integration, bitbucket

I'm creating a vanilla Angular project and uploading it to Bitbucket. It runs locally and I can build it into dist with no errors nor warnings. Now, I'd like to expose it on my Azure account. There's quite a lot of [material showing how to](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/05/10/use-azure-portal-to-setup-continuous-delivery-for-web-app-on-linux/) **but** most of it is [a bit aged](https://prmadi.com/running-angular2-app-on-azure-app-services-with-ci-cd/) (the options in Azure has changed) and/or the authors make it easy and [use another options for the source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HJCIJZBMDmY) (I target specifically Bitbucket).

Optimally, I'd like the following to happen.

1. Trigger by a push, get the files from the BitBucket repo.
2. Execute the command *ng build --prod* (or *npm run build*).
3. Copy over the artifacts from *dist* to the root of the app.

Checking the logs, I see two sections of relevance. First one is *Generating deployment script*, while the second is *Running deployment command*. The end of those as well as the label in the portal imply that it's all good and dandy. Well, it's not.

> Using the following command to generate deployment script: 'azure site deploymentscript -y --no-dot-deployment -r "D:\home\site\repository" -o "D:\home\site\deployments\tools" --node --sitePath "D:\home\site\repository"'.
>   Generating deployment script for node.js Web Site
>   Generated deployment script files
>
> Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
>   Handling node.js deployment.
>
> KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
>   Deleting file: 'hostingstart.html'
>   Copying file: '.angular-cli.json'
>   Copying file: '.editorconfig'
>   ...
>   Copying file: 'src\index.html'
>   Copying file: 'src\assets\logo.png'
>   Copying file: 'src\assets_favicon.ico'
>   Copying file: 'src\environments\environment.prod.ts'
>   Copying file: 'src\environments\environment.ts'
>
> Invalid start-up command "ng serve" in package.json. Please use the format "node ".
>       Looking for app.js/server.js under site root.
>       Missing server.js/app.js files, web.config is not generated
>
> The package.json file does not specify node.js engine version constraints.
>       The node.js application will run with the default node.js version 6.9.1.
>       Selected npm version 3.10.8
>       web@0.0.0 D:\home\site\wwwroot
>       +-- @angular/animations@5.2.9
>       ...
>       `-- zone.js@0.8.26
>
> Finished successfully.

However, when I access the page, only the default document provided by MS shows. I've tried accessing the image files but failed (not sure if I got the link wrong or if those aren't there). All in all, I feel that I'm barking up the wrong tree. Trying to repeat the steps (possibly with slight changes), produced a website that says *You do not have permission to view this directory or page*, which gets me to a confused position where I see no rational next step in troubleshooting.

Suggestions on what I might be missing?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this? https://bitbucket.org/mojall/bitbucket-pipelines-deploy-to-azure?_ga=2.166373756.39458287.1531701009-708085054.1531701009